# How to connect to socket.IO using swift?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am working with socket io using AppCoda  [this](https://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/) Tutorial.  connect to socket server using `node.js` and `swift`, working fine , But it was group chat if we send the message it is showing to all users available in the socket . But How can we send messages one to one I am using `socketio/socket.io-client-swift` till now I can able to connect the socket after that what I will follow to create one to one chat.

As per my search we need to create a chatroom for two persons,But I am not sure Please let me know.